# How do I convert a list of image files into separate pdf files in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert multiple image-files into separate pdf files using *PIL*. I am trying to use a loop with two lists `imagefile_list_1` which is a list of the file paths with the images I want to convert `imagefile_list_2` which is a list of the same file paths but with **.pdf** instead. This is the code I am currently using:

```
    from PIL import Image
    
    i = 0
    while i <= len(imagefile_list_1):
        i +=1
        image = Image.open(imagefile_list_1[i])
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image.save(imagefile_list_2[i])
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file
```

Comment: What is the error in this code? Can you please explain what problems you are facing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your exact error, but `-2` errors when writing files often correlate to non-existing folders. Are those target folders existing? If not, create them beforehand - or check in code and create them if needed. On another issue: Increment `i` at the end of the loop. Otherwise, you'll be missing the first image in your list, which has index `0`. Also, it should be `while i < len(imagefile_list_1)`, not less or equal.